# How can I switch to the latest ruby on AWS Linux?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

AWS Linux 2012.03 now comes with ruby 1.9.3

To install it (as per the docs):

```
sudo yum install ruby19
```

But `ruby -v` shows `1.8.7`. How would I switch it over 1.9.3 (If its already there there would be no need to use RVM yes?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby version 1.9 should be available under the name `ruby19` or `ruby1.9`. `ruby` is just a symbolic link that points to default version of ruby.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Trying the below

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't sure which one it is.

Answer (score 19):

The right way to do this on Amazon Linux is:

```
sudo yum update (to get latest version of Amazon Linux (2013.09 at time of this answer)
yum install ruby19 
alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9
```

Comment: These are the steps called out in the official release notes:

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.09-release-notes/

Answer (score 8):

Supplementing @baboonWorksFine's answer, there are a number of 1.9 commands that can be symlinked as their undecorated equivalents. What I did was:

```
sudo -s
for f in /usr/bin/*1.9
do
  ln -s $f ${f%1.9}
done
```

That way, you don't accidentally miss any commands that need aliasing.

Comment: Manually modifying the symlinks may work for now, but it may also be overwritten later on when an installer such as `yum` updates. The correct way in Amazon Linux is to use the `alternatives` command. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

If you do this:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ruby*
```

you will probably see this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Apr 26 18:27 /usr/bin/ruby -> ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3720 Mar 29 08:29 /usr/bin/ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3888 Mar 29 12:26 /usr/bin/ruby1.9
```

This is well self explained. So what you wanna do is:

```
rm /usr/bin/ruby && ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.9 /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Manually modifying the symlinks may work for now, but it may also be overwritten later on when an installer such as `yum` updates.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one simple solution and cleaner.

```
alternatives --config ruby
```

That will list all versions of Ruby you installed through yum. All you have to do is choose the number listed there and hit enter.

Comment: worked for me with `sudo alternatives --config ruby` to use ruby 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I used @Ian Dickinson's answer, but added an "f" to the ln options to force it to overwrite the existing link. So the code is:

```
sudo -s
for f in /usr/bin/*1.9
do
  ln -fs $f ${f%1.9}
done
```